# Check for string in a file, extract variables and write into another file

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I will be getting two or more files with random filenames starting from "createxxxx.out"

Any of these two files can contain a string called **Fail**.

I have to search for that "Fail" string and Fetch two variables(Variable1 , Variable2) present in the same file (file which contains String '**Fail**') and print those two variables in some another file(here i am trying to print it in **Error.log** file).

I have tried the below script, its not working:

```
if grep -q "Fail" create_*;

then

   grep 'Variable1\|Variable2' create_*  > Error.log
   echo -e "Creation Failed"
fi
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the AND operator?

Comment: I am nt sure, I was trying to fetch those two variables using AND operator.Now i changed it.

Comment: There is no `AND` operator; do you mean `&&`? Show the failing code that you actually run.

Comment: mention the format of the variables in that file

Comment: Please provide a sample input

Comment: Also, please define "not working "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh
#use 'egrep' for multiple keyword search
#this script will search for fail/Fail/fAiL words
#from all files starts with 'create'
#and save in fileanme_error.log if fail/variable(s) found
#
# 'egrep -i' - option also can be used for variable search
# with ignoring case sensitivity

for file in $(ls -1 create_*)
do

 grep -qi 'fail' $file

 if [ $? -eq 0 ];then

   egrep 'Variable1|Variable2' $file  > $file_Error.log
   echo -e "Creation Failed for file: $file"

 fi

done
```

---

This line will save unique keyword(s):

```
egrep 'Variable1|Variable2' $file|sort -u  > $file_Error.log
```

Comment: What if I want to write only the variables wit unique values to Error. Log file

Comment: write only unique variable names? or unique variable names+value? - see updated answer